# Is there an annotation to define a multi column index in jpa2

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa, jpa-2.0

Hibernate provides a mechanism to define multi column indexes via the [Table](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/api/org/hibernate/annotations/Table.html#indexes()). Is there a way to specify this is an ORM agnostic fashion via JPA or JPA2 (e.g. using the javax.persistence.* APIs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as hinted in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725545/how-to-create-indexes-on-multiple-columns/3725795#3725795) to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725545/how-to-create-indexes-on-multiple-columns), there is no standardized way, you have to use provider extensions for that (when they exist).

Comment: just curious to know, as per your earlier suggestion we are using hibernate annotations for this purpose. It makes sense to support this, when JPA already has support for single column Index annotation. Just my 2 cents

Comment: @user339108 I personally agree and I'd like JPA to support this too. Maybe in a future version.

Comment: @user339108 Can you provide an example to your statement "JPA already has support for single column Index annotation". I couldn't find any annotation allowing this other then the @Index annotation provided by Hibernate.

Comment: `@Column(unique=true)` imposes an index upon a column. Non-unique indexes are not supported by JPA 2.0. 2.1+ is much more versatile.

Answer (score 10):

Just came about the very same issue using Hibernate 4.3.8 with JPA 2.1 integration.
It seems, mjaggard's answer is correct. However, the given example of usage looks like this:

```
@Index(name="EMP_NAME_INDEX", columnList={"F_NAME", "L_NAME"})
```

I don't know if this ever worked. I do know that in my case with JPA 2.1 the value of `columnList` is not an array but a String. So for me, the desired two-column index can be defined in the following way:

```
@Index(name="EMP_NAME_INDEX", columnList="F_NAME,L_NAME")
```

That is, just use a comma to separate the column names in a single string. This worked for me using a Postgres DBMS. I checked back and the index was successfully created over both columns.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to declare multi-column index in JPA 2.1 Here is a sample `Entity` class that demonstrates multi-column indexing.

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"product_id","store_id"}))
class MyEntity {
    @Column(name="product_id")
    private String productId;

    @Column(name="store_id")
    private Long storeId;
}
```

Please note that `columnNames` must be the name of the columns in DB, not the attribute name.

Comment: Unique constraints aren't necessarily indexed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible using JPA 2.1 as seen in the specification here:

http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-pfd-spec/index.html

on page 445 it states that

> The Index annotation is used in schema generation
>
> columnList (Required) The names of the columns to be included in the index.

An example of usage can be seen here:

http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/but-what-if-im-not-querying-by-id.html